# MySQL prepared stmt issue

Tags: mysql

I've the following simple table structures and prepared statement:

```
create table junk1(name varchar(10), state varchar(10));
create table junk2(state varchar(100));
insert into junk2(state)values("state like '%Tex%'"),("state like '%Neb%'"),("state like '%Was%'");
insert into junk1(name, state) values ('asa', 'Texas'), ('dff', 'Washing'), ('fgfgf', 'Oklahoma'), ('bbb', 'Nevada'), ('hhh', 'Texas'), ('jjj', 'Nebraska');
SET @va = '';
select group_concat(state separator ' OR ') into @va from junk2;
PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'select * from junk1 where ?';
execute stmt1 using @va;
deallocate prepare stmt1;
```

I'm not getting the results as expected. I get NO results. I'm I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use syntax elements as parameters in a prepared statement, i.e. you can't pass an entire where clause as a parameter, only values.

You may want to concatenate your where clause instead:

```
select group_concat(state separator '" OR "') into @va from junk2;
set @clause = concat('select * from junk1 where "', @va, '"');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @clause;
```

Comment: YOU ARE DA BOSS. I couldn't use concat directly instead made a small change to your answer: instead of using concat in the prepare stmt, i assigned it to another variable and like this: PREPARE stmt1 FROM @ba; EXECUTE stmt1

Comment: OK, wasn't sure about this, changing my answer accordingly

Comment: you are right Psi..i figured it out and accepted your answer..may thousand blessings be bestowed upon ya.

Comment: Glad I could have helped. However, be careful to validate your data as this approach is possibly vulnerable to sql injection attacks. So do not select from any column containing unfiltered, user-generated content.

Comment: Will Do My Good Sir! Thanks for the help!